# How do I add A new riser to my steps without tearing out the old riser?

Tags: stairs

One riser is fine, but the other rotted out at the front corner of the top step.  I can’t take it out without tearing the porch apart.  I have decided to just add the new riser flush to the old one since the old one is strong below the top step and along the bottom of the old top rise.   What is the best way to attach these two 2x10” pieces.  I bought two lag bolts and two three inch heavy duty screws with bolt type heads.  Should I glue as well?

Comment: I bet you can take it out, if you cut it into pieces first. photos will probably help.

Comment: Definitely needs an overview picture of the steps, then some detailed pics of the rot and of the points where the old one is attached. You might be able to get away with attaching the new to the old, then again, the old one might just continue to rot away leaving the new one hanging in space.